# static set value for parameter php function

Tags: php, function, static

I have a question.

i can set a static value as the default for a function?

for example:

```
class unameClass{

   protected static $var1 = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');

   public static function get($var1 = static::$var1)
   {
      return static::randomElement($var1);
   }
}
```

but this is wrong.
I'm currently doing so:

```
class unameClass{

   protected static $var1 = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');

   public static function get($var1 = null)
   {
      $var1 = is_null($var1) ? static::$var1 : $var1;

      return static::randomElement($var1);
   }
}
```

Comment: "i can set a static value as the default for a function?" no

Comment: So,please clearify your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not do this. As it is written in the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default)

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a
>   variable, a class member or a function call.

Static variable is a class member and it can not be used as default value for function parameter.

I think your approach is good and in fact this is what I was going to recomment you to do.